# Add margin on top of the background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, margin, padding

I want to add margin on top of the background image. Here is my background-image css code

```
body {
  background-image:url(Images/Home.png);
  background-position:top;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

I tried to add `margin-top:10px;` in the css body code, but it's not working. Only the `div`'s moving

Comment: Which `div`? You are only modifying the `body`.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following instead of the one you have for background-position?

```
background-position:0px 10px;
```

Comment: It worked! unfortunately the background image change position to the left. Do you know how to fix it? I tried setting the position to center, not working either.

Comment: background-position:center 10px;

Answer (score 0):

This will offset the background-image from the top by 10 pixels:

```
background-position: top 10px;
```

Comment: tried, it's not working and the background image change its position to the left

Answer (score 0):

You could add a div before the body, set it's height to 10px.  Should give you the spacing you're looking for.